# Stop flex overlapping

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following navigation which I have made responsive by using `display:flex`:

```css
#header-nav { display: flex; flex-grow: 1; background: #707276; background: rgba(112,114,118,0.75); }

#header-nav .nav-item { display: flex; flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 0; }
#header-nav .nav-link { display: block; color: #ffffff; display: flex; flex-grow: 1; justify-content: center; align-items: center; white-space: nowrap; }

#header-nav > .nav-item > .nav-link { box-sizing: border-box; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none; padding: 15px 0; position: relative; transition: color 0.5s ease-in-out; font-size: 115.385%; font-family: VegurRegular; }
#header-nav > .nav-item > .nav-link:hover { color: #000000; }
#header-nav > .nav-item > .nav-link:after { content: ''; display: block; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; height: 5px; opacity: 0; transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out; background-color: #36383a; }
#header-nav > .nav-item > .nav-link:hover:after { opacity: 0.8; }


#header-nav .home { flex-grow: 0; flex-basis: auto; padding: 0 50px; }
#header-nav .nav-item.home > .nav-link { display: block; }
#header-nav .nav-item.home > .nav-link:after { display: none; }
```

```html
<ul id="header-nav">
    <li class="nav-item home">
        <a href="/" class="nav-link">
            <span id="logo-text" class="sprite">Logo</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#shop" class="nav-link">Shop</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#tiling" class="nav-link">Tiling Ideas</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#advice" class="nav-link">Advice</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#retailers" class="nav-link">Find a Retailer</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, the logo stays the same width, whilst the rest is responsive.  But if you use the fullpage link and then make the width of the screen smaller, you will see the links start to overlap each other.  Is there any way to stop this from happening using `flex`?

I know I can find a route with using display table that would achieve the same thing but I would prefer to use display flex.

Comment: You could use `flex-wrap: wrap`

Comment: @NenadVracar this would cause the links to wrap which I don't want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `white-space: nowrap;` as it is is inherently not responsive.

```css
#header-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #707276;
  background: rgba(112, 114, 118, 0.75);
}
#header-nav .nav-item {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
#header-nav .nav-link {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
#header-nav > .nav-item > .nav-link {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 115.385%;
  font-family: VegurRegular;
}
#header-nav > .nav-item > .nav-link:hover {
  color: #000000;
}
#header-nav > .nav-item > .nav-link:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #36383a;
}
#header-nav > .nav-item > .nav-link:hover:after {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
#header-nav .home {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
  padding: 0 50px;
}
#header-nav .nav-item.home > .nav-link {
  display: block;
}
#header-nav .nav-item.home > .nav-link:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="header-nav">
  <li class="nav-item home">
    <a href="/" class="nav-link">
      <span id="logo-text" class="sprite">Logo</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#shop" class="nav-link">Shop</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#tiling" class="nav-link">Tiling Ideas</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#advice" class="nav-link">Advice</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#retailers" class="nav-link">Find a Retailer</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Alternatively, consider media queries to reduce the font size at lower screen sizes.**

Comment: Unfortunately I don't want the text to wrap - I was just looking for a way of the screen reducing to the size of the list with all the text on one row (as it would do when using display:table) - unfortunately I can't go the table route as I use flex to grow my link to the size of the logo.  I'm going to use media queries to change to a mobile burger menu but was just wondering if the above was possible or if flex would always overlap in my circumstance

Comment: If you tell text not to wrap then you're going to have to expect overflow/overlapping. `white-space:nowrap` is inherently not responsive.

Comment: not necessarily: https://jsfiddle.net/pyyLowev/ you see it just pushes the text off the screen rather than overlapping.  I take it there is no property of flex that allows for it to do something similar in taking the width of the contents rather than just resizing to the calculated width

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Either you want it responsive or you don't...I don't see text being pushed off the screen as responsive.

Comment: To be fair the responsive thing is a red herring as you will get the burger menu by the time it gets that small.  I just have a search box that opens up and causes the text top get squashed and overlap.  I'll just have to think of another way to open up the textbox